# Why is it that a nonzero vector space over an infinite field is an infinite set?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading through my linear algebra textbook (Friedberg, 5th) and I read this in the linear in/dependence section:

"Suppose that $V$ is a vector space over an infinite field and that $W$ is a subspace of $V$. Unless $W$ is the zero subspace, $W$ is an infinite set."

Why is $W \neq \left\{ 0\right\}$ an infinite set?

Comment: You need to exclude the example that $\{0\}$ is a finite subspace of any vector space.

Comment: Note that the information about $V$ does not carry much meaning here. $W$ itself is a non-zero vector space over an infinite field. Follow from there.

Comment: You've now made three cosmetic edits to your question. Consider looking at the answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker I _have_ looked at the answer. I am editing my question for simplicity and clarity for users who see this question in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick any nonzero element of $W$ and consider its scalar multiples.